# How to access array element without index ([])

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am getting a response of an api that includes an array that has many objects inside of it . The objects positions change overtime. Therefore if I use array[0] the object it returns might change depending on the current arrangement of the objects. How can I access a specific object in the array **regardless of the index** so that even if the indexes positions change the same object is accessed?

Comment: do your object has something unique? like id or unique name

Comment: What is the meaning of *"same object"*? If you are getting the response from an API, it will always be brand new objects in the array. Do you have any property like `id` in the object to identify it? [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're gonna need some way to identify the object you're looking for. For example, if the object has a specific property with a specific value, you can use that to find this object in the array. To actually find the object, you can use [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

For example, if you're always looking for the object with an `id` of `123`:

```js
const testArray = [{ id: 123 }, { id: 456 }, { id: 789 }];
const idToSearchFor = 123;
const objectWithSpecificId = testArray.find(
    obj => obj.id === idToSearchFor
);
```

If you want to find multiple objects instead of one, you can use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const testArray = [{ id: 123 }, { id: 456 }, { id: 789 }];
const idsFilter = [123, 789];
const matchingObjects = testArray.filter(
    obj => idsFilter.includes(obj.id)
);
console.log(matchingObjects.length); // 2
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way by any chance in which I can find more than one element without having to repeat the code? ( A way in which I put all the IDs I want and I get all the objects which contain all the IDs I put where I can use a loop to extract what I want from all of them at once) ?

Comment: @AkonZ In this case you can use Array.prototype.filter instead, I've updated my answer with an example!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) or [Find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method get your object

```
var result = jsObjects.filter(obj => {
  return obj.b === "object1" // or === 5 (if it's an int)
})

var result = jsObjects.find(obj => {
  return obj.b === "object1" // or === 5 (if it's an int)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a unique property on the object. Then you can use the `find` method. Something like `const target = myArray.find(obj => obj.id === "thing-im-looking-for");`

Answer (score 0):

If each object has a unique identifier you can use simply use `find` array method. It might look like this:

```js
var result = objectsArr.find(obj => {
  return obj.id === id
})
```